# Polymer - How to use Iron-Selector's Selectable property

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I'm trying to make just one item selectable of my list. I'm assuming this should stop them from routing to the other pages if I click on the other links if only one of them is selectable. I did what I had to do to make Chip selectable and it doesn't seem to be functioning as I thought. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<iron-selector selected="[[page]]"  attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation" selectable="item" >
      <a id="menuitem" name="view1" href="/">Super Wide</a>
      <a id="menuitem" name="view2" href="/view2">Wide Format</a>
      <a id="menuitem" name="view3" href="/view3">Textile</a>
      <a id="menuitem" name="view4" href="/view4">Bulk</a>
      <a id="menuitem" name="view5" class="item" href="/view5">Chip</a>
      <a id="menuitem" name="view6" href="/view6">Spare Parts</a>

    </iron-selector>
```

Comment: Try using `selectable=".item"`, it's a class selector you're trying to use so it needs the dot

Comment: I had tried the dot earlier and it still wasn't working the way I wanted it to.

Comment: As @Alan said, `selectable` is a class selector it needs to leading with dot. I think this what you want (stop <a>) can't be done with `iron-selector` because selectable didn't stop click event.